# Sprite rotation with collision PIXIJS

Tags: javascript, 2d, sprite, collision-detection, pixi.js

I have a problem with my pixiJS App. I have many sprites that I can move in my scene. My goal is to create a plan with collisions between sprites, for that I use the bump plugin and the rectangleCollision function: https://github.com/kittykatattack/bump/

`let collision = b.rectangleCollision(selectCont,c2,true,false,true);`

It works (the middle case on the pic) if my sprites have no rotation but if I rotate the sprites the collisions don't work (left and right case in the pic).

[image: Screenshot]

I think it's a problem with sprite bounds but I have no idea.

I have an array with all my sprites and I have a function when I right click on a sprite it applies a rotation and when I want to apply my rotation it does work but my collision is not correct

```
for (var j = 0; j < cont.length; j++) {
  var c2 = cont[j];
  b.contain(c2, {x: 0, y: 0, width: 2400, height: 1800}, true);
  
  if(selectCont!=c2){
    if(activeCollision == true){
       let collision = b.hit(selectCont,c2,endCollision,false,true);
    }
  }
}

// function to apply a rotation to sprite
function rotate(){
  this.rotation -= Math.PI/4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rotation` property of sprites defaults to rotating the sprite around the top left vertice, not the center. The pivot point can be changed with the sprites `pivot` property, as shown here:

```
sprite.pivot.set(sprite.width/2,sprite.height/2);
```

This will set the sprites pivot point to be right in the center of itself.